# what is the main difference between Spring and Rest services

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to J2EE. I found that Spring MVC could also perform the same tasks as REST. What is the main difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC is a framework which allows you to create RESTful Web sites and application whereas Representational State Transfer (REST) is a software architecture style consisting of guidelines and best practices for creating scalable web services

Comment: We can even create web services using Spring right?

Comment: You can create web services using the Spring MVC framework, yes.

Comment: @user you have quite the user name.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is a framework (Struts, Spring, ...)
Rest is a message architecture

Comment: So, could we just use Spring in place of REST. Are there any limitations.

Comment: You use Spring for creating Rest services via controllers. Spring is not mandatory for creating Rest services. You can do it many ways.